# Can MySQL stored procedures be used for anything Java is used for?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i.e, can we just use stored procedures for everything? In a web-site backed by a  DB that is.

Comment: No, Clearance in your question.

Comment: We're working on a distributed web app. My team-mate wants to use MySql stored procedures for most everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored Procedures have their benefits:

- Minimize traffic back & forth between the application & database, wasting bandwidth
- MVC: Separation of persistence layer
- Scale loads better than application code (IE: `ORDER BY` will always trump application code)

Stored Procedure Cons:

- Database dependency - ANSI is becoming more widely supported, but stored procedure code (not the query/queries in them) is not standardized at this time

### Conclusion

Yes, stored procedures & functions can do most of what you'd probably ever want to do with data.  The decision to use them is determined by design choices - to be database agnostic, most would not use stored procedures.  Choose what best suits the requirements, not your preference.

Comment: With regard to the original question - using stored procedures 'for everything' - it's almost certainly a very bad idea.

Comment: as in "Yes, stored procedures & functions can do most of what you'd probably ever want to do with data", you mean? I agree.

Comment: @magma: "most" isn't an absolute, while "almost certainly is a very bad idea" is dangerously close.

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. *And*, that's probably a bad idea.

See: [Arguments for/against Business Logic in stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484516/arguments-for-against-business-logic-in-stored-procedures)

Comment: Thank You - golden answer here

Comment: Not a great question to refer to - the issue is subjective/argumentative, and really depends on the application design.

Comment: @omg *Because* the issue is subjective *and* it depends on the application design *and* we don't know much about Ada's application design, it's a worth read.

Comment: So, you're unable to ask for clarification?  Or just unwilling, when you could've supplied the link on the premise of being an exact duplicate?